# Capistrano + Git : repository local to production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, capistrano

I am trying to do 'deploy:cold' for my app. The git repo is local to
my deployment server (i.e. I only have one server for everything and I
don't host my code on github).

Here is the transcript (replaced my app name with "myapp" for privacy)

```
  * executing `deploy:cold'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote /home/mrichman/git/myapp.git master"
fatal: '/home/mrichman/git/myapp.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/myapp.com/releases/20100218203108; true"
    servers: ["myapp.com"]
Password:
    [myapp.com] executing command
    command finished
Command git ls-remote /home/mrichman/git/myapp.git master returned status code 32768
```

Here is my deploy.rb: http://pastie.org/831424

I have also tried

```
set :repository, "deploy@localhost:/home/mrichman/git/myapp.git"
```

but that gives me

```
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just ran into the same problem. The key is to not use deploy_via copy but rather set :local_repository

This should be set to the URL you use to access the repository from your development computer/laptop.

So mine has

```
set :repository, "file:///srv/git/myapp.git"
set :local_repository, "nameOfHostFromSSHConfig:/srv/git/myapp.git"
```

Seems to have worked. Just remember to then remove the deploy_via copy line as well.

Comment: I now have the following, which also fails:

set :repository, "file:///var/git/myapp.git"
set :local_repository, "localhost:/var/git/myapp.git"

executing locally: "git ls-remote localhost:/var/git/hireexchange.git master"
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Comment: Are you developing on the same box? If you are I'd imagine :local_repository, "file://var/git/myapp.git" would work.

localhost should be replaced with whatever the hostname is that you connect to from your assumed remote workstation.

Also I've found that if you have submodules you'll run into more problems doing a deploy like this, because the modules are set to point to a remote URL.

Very annoying, but can be solved using .ssh/config on your server under the user you deploy as.

Comment: Hi guys. If it makes any difference, git on my local and remote machine required different paths, hence I needed set :git_local /path/to/remote/git and set :git /usr/bin/git (note these do not require the ssh in the beginning).

Comment: I used `set :repository, "/home/#{user}/path/to/repo.git"` instead of the `file:///...` line and it worked like freaking magic!  Thanks

Comment: In Capistrano 3, replace `:repository` with `:repo_url`. `:local_repository` seems unnecessary, at least it was for me.

Comment: @RussK, could you share the entire setup please? can't find anything that's gonna work.

Answer (score 1):

Log in as the user of the site you are deploying to and try this to see if your user has permission to access that directory:

ls -la /home/mrichman/git/myapp.git

If you get a Permission denied error then you'll have to make sure that you set permissions on the enclosing directories of the repository that allow the deployment script to access the files.

Comment: I have verified that my deploy user has full read access to /home/mrichman/git/myapp.git. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Try logging into the deploy user account and typing out the failed command manually: "git ls-remote /home/mrichman/git/myapp.git master", it will probably give you the same error, and if it does, log in as the mrichman user and try it as that user. If that still gives an error, which I bet will happen, then you will want to go into the "/home/mrichman/git/myapp.git" directory and type "git status" and if that fails, you'll need to check that the contents of that directory indeed contain a git repository.

Comment: When I do `git ls-remote` as either my deploy user or my own user I appear to get success: `aa30ffc814fffd96b168ffec7224aeb9fe9df161 refs/heads/master`. I believe `git status` only works on work trees, and not the actual repository.

As an experiment, I pushed my repo to Codaset, and my `cap deploy` works fine that way. I can (and probably should) continue that way, as it is unsafe to keep one's SCM on their web server :)

Comment: I just ran into this problem and it was because I was running cap deploy:update as sudo.  My local user could run git ls-remote correctly but sudo git ls-remote was giving me the same error.  I finally tracked it down to the fact that my local user had the correct ssh keys for the remote git repository but root didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have written the correct git repo with caring **case-sensitive** writing! (I faced the same problem, it just solved)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was actually related to a known-hosts problem. All I had to do was make sure the remote git server was in my known hosts (trying to SSH into it for the first time will prompt you to add this yourself), and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If `local_repository` is set, then Capistrano uses the value of `respository` from the deployment server and the value of `local_respository` from the development server. [Or something like that.](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Significant-Configuration-Variables)

My configuration worked like so:

```
set :repository, "/home/#{user}/path/to/repo.git"
set :local_repository, "myserver.com:path/to/repo.git"
```