# What are the differences between :repo_url, :repository and :local_repository

Tags: ssh, capistrano, capistrano3

In capistrano 3.1: What are the differences between :repo_url, :repository and :local_repository?

I've been trying to find the best way to do deploys. I have my code hosted locally in my office and I deploy to AWS. All of the engineers do deploys from home.

My workflow right now is:

1. VPN
2. Set forward agent true in .ssh/config
3. set RemoteForward to the local server hosting our git repos
4. Open ssh tunnel to AWS Deploy with capistrano and restart unicorn
5. Close ssh tunnel to AWS

I came across this SO question: [Capistrano + Git : repository local to production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293212/capistrano-git-repository-local-to-production-server) and it sounds like this question could solve having to do the remote forward.

What are the differences between :repo_url, :repository and :local_repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:repository is the Capistrano v2 version of specifying the remote repo you want to grab files from

:repo_url is the Capistrano v3 version of :repository, so depending on your version you'll use one or the other.

:local_repository is a variable you set if you want to grab files from a repo located on your own computer, or whichever computer you're developing on. So for :local_repository you would see something like

```
set :local_repository, "/home/eric/my_projs/proj1"
```

I found these answers at
    http://blog.huangzhimin.com/2013/11/02/upgrade-to-capistrano3/